# Как изменить код, чтобы не ругался?

Tags: android-sdk, android-fragment, аннотации

Есть класс для взаимодействия с фрагментами:

```
class FragmentControl{

private AppCompatActivity activity;

FragmentControl(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

private FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    return fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
}

void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}

void removeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}

void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}}
```

Как изменить данный код, чтобы не ругался на метод:

```
private FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    return fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
}
```

а именно на `beginTransaction()`

Пишет, что

> This transaction should be completed with a commit() call less... (Ctrl+1) 
>   After creating a FragmentTransaction, you typically need to commit it as well

Или по русски:

> Эта транзакция должна быть завершена с вызовом commit () less ... (Ctrl + 1)
>   После создания FragmentTransaction вам также необходимо выполнить его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить код следующим образом

```
class FragmentControl {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    FragmentControl(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    private FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        return fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }

    void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment).commit();
    }

    void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

Также в помощь [-1-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34086865/5330439), [-2-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295368/5330439)